# How to prevent IntelliJ IDEA from deleting unused packages?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working with intelliJ and my problem is when I start to import some temporary unused packages into my class file intellij delete those line within a second.

how can I turn off this not so nice feature?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Disable `File | Settings` | `Editor` | `General` | `Auto Import` | **Optimize imports on the fly**.

Normally you don't need to add imports manually, IDEA does it for you.

Comment: While this the common case in Java, with Scala and implicit conversions, things are not as smooth. For example, it keeps removing `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`. But IntelliJ doesn't auto-import when I type `.asScala` at the end of an expression that returns a Java collection. So IMHO the option should be off by default for Scala code.

Comment: For me, the Auto Import option was under `Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import > Optimize imports on the Fly`, as in @merrick's answer. v14.1.4

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'm using IDEA 15.0.1 Build 143.382 and do not have this enabled. However, IDEA removes my imports whenever I comment out lines. Any idea?

Comment: how can I disable this for a single Kotlin file? The damn IDE is constantly inserting java `String` and `Set` imports into this one file and it produces error messages of course. Very annoying since it happens whenever imports are optimized for it

Comment: Groovy seems to be affected as well. Some imports are marked as unused but they are required for compilation. I have noted this happens specially when using inner classes of an extended class.

Comment: God forbid you have two packages with the same name!!! This "remove unused imports" feature drives me crazy. Auto add YES. But don't remove a package I already used IntelliJ. BTW, this is missing in IntelliJ Ultimate Golang plugin.

Answer (score 17):

For Scala developers: you can have **enabled** 
`Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import > Optimize imports on the fly` 

but add **exclusions** into

```
Settings > Editor > Code Style > Scala > Imports always marked as used:
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that and that drove me crazy. Very useful for Scala specially when you start using a lot things like Cats or ScalaZ...

Answer (score 12):

In Intellij 14 :
`Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import > Optimize imports on the fly.`

Answer (score 3):

(Update)
For the Scala developers out there, you can have 1/2 the cake and eat the other 1/2 now: disable the auto-optimize for *just scala*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me while using Go, this was caused by optimizing imports on save. IntelliJ IDEA -> Prefernces -> Tools -> Actions on Save -> Optimize imports.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are obviously the way to go. Here's another quick fix (a bad one at that) is to simply use it somewhere in your code

```js
if (0) console.log(LibraryName.version);
```

This should only be a temporary measure though.