# IntelliJ keeps removing the import of context.dispatcher from akka tutorial

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka, executioncontext

I am following the akka-in-action tutorial and in chapter 2, there is a class (https://github.com/RayRoestenburg/akka-in-action/blob/master/chapter2/src/main/scala/com/goticks/RestInterface.scala):

```
trait RestApi extends HttpService with ActorLogging { actor: Actor =>
  import context.dispatcher
  import com.goticks.TicketProtocol._
  ...
```

The `import context.dispatcher` is never used, but it is defined with a comment:

```
  /**
   * Returns the dispatcher (MessageDispatcher) that is used for this Actor.
   * Importing this member will place an implicit ExecutionContext in scope.
   */
  implicit def dispatcher: ExecutionContextExecutor
```

However, IntelliJ keeps marking the import as "unused" and removing it upon "optimize imports" causing an error `value pipeTo is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[Any]`.

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ that this import is not intended to be "used", but just to simply provide a context?

Or should the tutorial be updated to not use such "unused import"?

Comment: Intellij's "optimize imports" functionality is buggy. I tend to turn off removal of unused imports in the settings and only use it to add new imports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent IntelliJ IDEA from deleting unused packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154912/how-to-prevent-intellij-idea-from-deleting-unused-packages)

Comment: Nope. It is not about disabling deleting all imports of unused packages, but about disabling deleting imports which are "used", but IDEA thinks they are "not used".

Comment: Do I need to edit the question to get rid of the "duplicate remark" box?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This looks like issue [SCL-9326](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9326) to me. IntelliJ 15 has a nice fix for this: press alt-enter (on a Mac) and select "mark this import as always used in this project".

Comment: Note you have to disable "Optimize imports on the fly" for this to work

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings - editor - general - auto import
and add the package to the "Exclude from import and completion" list
[image]

You can also disable the "Optimize import on the fly" so that it will not remove your imports without your explicit request

Comment: Hmm, nice solution, but there is separate "Java" and "Scala" sections. In "Scala" section the options are the same except "Exclude from Import and Completion"

Comment: I thought something from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Managing+Imports+in+Scala could help, but it doesn't seem so.