# How prevent Intellij Idea from removing unused imports?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For some external tool it is needed to keep several unused imports (but not all) in java classes. Is there a way to mark them to prevent deleting by IntelliJ Idea?

Answer (score 0):

[How to prevent IntelliJ IDEA from deleting unused packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154912/how-to-prevent-intellij-idea-from-deleting-unused-packages)

Basically, you need to disable automatic import optimization.

Comment: No this is not a solution, because somebody with enabled this option simply deletes all files before comit.

Comment: @cherry this is the default. If you don't want it to happen, you have to turn it off.

Comment: @JonnyHenly probably, if I had those fancy superpowers but I don't.

Comment: It's actually better as an answer now that OP has clarified his question, via the comment on your answer : ) And you can flag this question as a duplicate via the [flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148529/hw-prevent-intellij-idea-from-removing-unused-imports#) link underneath the question's tags.

Comment: @Cherry that seems to be a problem with the communication and understanding between people that can comit to a repo, not a problem with IntelliJ IDEA. Although I agree the option should be turned off by default.

Comment: @JonnyHenly there's probably a good meta-question there which is 'how to enforce certain IDEA defaults across a team' and 'turn these things off before they turns your SCM history into mashed potatoes'

Comment: how about changing the external tool which requires them?